# Issue with go package declaration containing more than 2 words separated by underscore

Tags: go, go-modules, go-packages, go-testing

everyone, I'm confused by what I'm seeing; I have the following `tree`:

```
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── server
    ├── server.go
    └── server_integration_test.go
```

Let's say my module name (`mod.go`) is `gotest`. Content of `server.go`:

```golang
package server

type MyStruct struct {
    Hello string
}

func (m MyStruct) SayHello() string {
    return m.Hello
}
```

Contents of `server_integration_test.go`:

```golang
package server_integration_test

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestIntegration(t *testing.T) {
    t.Errorf("just gonna fail!")
}
```

And finally my `main`.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gotest/server"
)

func main() {
    my := server.MyStruct{Hello: "my-struct"}
    fmt.Println("from mystruct", my.SayHello())
}
```

When I run `go build` (or `go test ./...`), I receive the following error:

```
main.go:5:2: found packages server (server.go) and server_integration (server_integration_test.go) in /tmp/gotest/server
```

But if I change my `server_integration_test.go` to be:

```golang
package server_test
// ...
```

Everything works.

Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: See [test packages](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages). The `go test` command supports two package names in _test.go files: the name of the package in the directory and the name of the package in the directory with a `_test` suffix.  The package name `server_integration_test` fails because it is not `server` or `server_test`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón write that as an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 2):

The supported package names for `server` package tests are `server` and `server_test`.

See [test packages](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages):

> 'Go test' recompiles each package along with any files with names matching the file pattern "*_test.go". These additional files can contain test functions, benchmark functions, and example functions. ...
>
> Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.

The `_test` suffix is applied to the name of the package under test (the documentation can be improved to make this fact more explicit).

Comment: Thank you Cerise, I tried finding the information from the link you provided, but I wasn't able to. Do you mind maybe adding a quote or something from there?